# Как избавится от повтора функции JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Здравствуйте уважаемы форумчане. Есть у меня проблемка небольшая. Через аякс загружаю на странице в `<div='peview'></div>` несколько фотографий `<img src='' class='imgList'>`. Изначально загрузка идёт с `php` странички, т.е. с помощью `json` проверяю есть ли они вообще у меня и, если есть загружаю в превью указанный выше. Теперь, с помощью `JQuery` я создаю обработчик удаления фотографий. Т.к. класс у них один и тот же, на сколько я знаю без итерации тут не обойтись, использую `each`. Теперь в общем:

```
$('.imgList').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        var deleteFile = confirm("Удалить эту фотографию?");
        if(deleteFile == true) {
            //Тут обработка...
        }
    });
});
```

Затем, на этой же страничке есть соответсвено форма загрузки изображений. Кто знаком с `jquery.wallform.js`? Вот я использую именно эту библиотеку. Смысл её в том что она загружает изображение на сервер, показывая превьюшку фотографии. Так вот эта самая превьюшка грузится в тот же `<div='peview'></div>`. Выходит что, при загрузке страницы загружается 5 фотографий и, с помощью формы догружается ещё одна. Проблема в том что итерация с `each` уже была воспроизведена при загрузке страницы, оно и понятно, по этому и не видит клика по нажатию на фото подгруженного в `<div='peview'></div>` через `wallform` аякс. Вот этот кусочек кода...

```
$('#photoimg').die('click').live('change', function() { 
    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview', 
         beforeSubmit:function(){ 

        $("#imageloadstatus").show();
        $("#imageloadbutton").hide();
         }, 
        success:function(){  // Тут у нас всё шикарно, фото загрузилось
        $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
        $("#imageloadbutton").show();
        }, 
        error:function(){ 
         $("#imageloadstatus").hide();
        $("#imageloadbutton").show();
        } }).submit();
});
```

....предоставляется так же от `wallform`. Я пробовал функцию с `each` обернуть в анонимную функцию и делал вызов этой функции в `success:function() {...}` Но получается так что обработчик вешается вновь и вновь и в итоге получается такая каша что ппц... В общем задача состоит в том что бы слушать id `#preview` постоянно. Итог в кратце: Страница загрузилась, фото ЗАгрузились, фото ДОгрузились через форму, навёл на фото, удалил фото. Прошу прощения за многословие, но я думаю что лучше объяснить от и до для лучшего понимания. Спасибо за ранее и за понимание :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться возможностью jQuery слушать события нажатия не на конкретный `.imgList`, а на родителя `#preview`.

Посмотрите документацию [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

В итоге, код обработчика может выглядеть вот так

```
$('#preview').on('click', '.imgList', function() {
    var deleteFile = confirm("Удалить эту фотографию?");
    if(deleteFile == true) {
        //Тут обработка...
    }
});
```

Пример использования:

```js
$('#preview').on('click', '.imgList', function() {
  var deleteFile = confirm("Удалить эту фотографию?");
  if (deleteFile == true) {
    //Тут обработка...
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preview">
  <div class="imgList">imgList 1</div>
  <div class="imgList">imgList 2</div>
  <div class="imgList">imgList 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @sergei1094 В таком случае, давайте html код в студию!

Comment: Я прошу прощения, свой код закоментировал и в конце не поставил закрывающийся тэг коментария. Ваш метод работает) Спасибо

Comment: @sergei1094 ничего страшного - бывает.

Answer (score 1):

Я обходил такую проблему с помощью метода `.off()`

Например: `$("#element").off().on("click", function(){});`

Если этот код запихать в цикл, то обработчик всегда будет один единственный.

**!!! Крайне важно `.off()` без параметров очищает все обработчики событий !!!**